# How to avoid CI from redirecting my call to KoolPHP controls

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to use KoolPHP to create UI in CodeIgniter (CI) framework. My problem is CI will redirect my call to KoolPHP controls by to index.php ..this causing >>> NetworkError: 404 Not Found

this is a example of what i mean;

my actual call is >>> "../KoolControls/KoolGrid/styles/default/default.css"

CI redirect to >>> "../index.php/KoolControls/KoolGrid/styles/default/default.css"

-> can anybody helpme on this..

thanks

m.zam

Comment: post your htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine   On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|asset|images|css|azza|js|robots.txt|KoolControls)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php/$1    [PT,L]

Comment: this is copy of my .htaccess file ... i also try without it also giving me the same problem

Comment: OK..i have to close this... got it working already.. thank GOD